# Identifying one-one /injective functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$R1=\{(x,y)∣x,y\in\mathbb{R},x+y>2\}$ this is a one-one function since every output maps to input in the domain.

$R2 = \{(x, y) \mid x, y \in \mathbb{R}, x>y \}$ this is a one-one function since every output maps to input in the domain.

$R3 = \{(x, y) \mid x+y= 12 \}$ this is not a one-one function since the domain and co-domain are not defined.

$R4 = \{(x, y) \mid x, y \in \mathbb{R}, y=x^2 \}$ this is a one-one function since every output maps to input in the domain.

Are my reasoning correct?

**Update:**

Here is the actual assignment question

[image]

Based on the comments, then this question is not framed correctly?

Comment: some of these aren’t even functions

Comment: $R_1,R_2$ are not functions, $R_3$ is not correctly defined. $R_4$ is not one-one since $-1$ and $1$ have the same image.

Comment: Why $R1, R2$ are not functions, while $R4$ is a function?

Comment: For $R_1$ we have that $1+2 > 2$ as well as $1+3 > 2$; thus, it is a relation but **not** a function.

Comment: Please excuse me, the study material given are simple and the assignment questions are super challenging for me.

Comment: The only thing that is probably misframed about this question is the missing "$x, y \in \Bbb R,$" in $R_3$. I suspect it was intended, but was left out accidently. As for the rest, you were expected to notice that $R_1$ and $R_2$ were not functions, and that $R_4$ was not one-one. To be a function, each value $x$ can have only one corresponding value of $y$. To be one-one (or injective), it must *also* be true that each value of $y$ only has one corresponding value of $x$.